# No tables are created when using code first EF

Tags: entity-framework, azure, frameworks, entity, connection-string

So I'm trying to deploy a database on Azure using EF code first. I have one model:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A first name is required.")]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Your firstname needs to be atleast 2 letters long")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]*$", ErrorMessage = "Your firstname can only contain letters")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name:")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

DataContext-class:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext() : base("DataContext")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
}
```

DataContextInitalizer-class:

```
public class DataContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DataContext>
{ 

}
```

In the global.asax-file to initalize the datacontext:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DataContextInitializer());
```

And then finally the string to connect to the database in the web.config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="DataContext" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:*.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=TestApi20180311012458_db;User ID=usernamehere;Password=passwordhere" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Thou no tables are created when building the solution. I dont know where I'm missing out. Can you see whats wrong?

Comment: When you build the solution, no database will be created, as no EF code has run.  The database initializer will run right after the model builder, which is executed once the database is accessed the first time (i.e. first query targeting it). I have however no idea what initializer would be used if you set the constructor to "just a new one". Usually EF recreates the database during initialization, using the CreateDatabaseIfNotExists initialization strategy, but using a new one might be the same as the null strategy, which will never create the db for you.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I have some EF code now in the seed method of the initializer but there's still no tables created in the database. Not sure what you mean by "no database is created" thou. I do have a database but theres no mapping from entities to tables going on.

Comment: what is the error you are getting then?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro no build or runtime error, the error is that there is no table generated. Since I have a dbset with user I should have a user-table but I dont, and I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

> Thou no tables are created when building the solution. I dont know where I'm missing out. Can you see whats wrong?

Your code just to connect Azure sql in your local project. And the data initialization just uses to initialize data in table. But your tables have not created yet. If you want to create table in Azure sql, you could use **[Migrations](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx)**.

Azure sql connection string in web.config:

```html
 <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnectionStringName" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:[databasename].database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=[databasename];Integrated Security=False;User Id=[username];Password=[password];Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />   
</connectionStrings>
```

Open **Tools> Nuget Mackage Manager>Package Manager Console**. Then enter the following code:

```html
Enable-migrations
Add-migration initial
update-database
```

[image]

After that, you could see the tables are created in Azure Sql.

For another way, you could use **publish tool** to connect to Azure sql and use Code First Migrations automatically. Do not need to use code to configure manually. Open **Publish settings** to configure Azure sql. Or you could read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase) to learn more details.

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful, you could mark it as answer to help other community members find. Thanks!